# exact value of the mean of a boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, mean, boxplot

I generated a `boxplot` with three variables ("Jahreszeit","Fracht","Bewirtschaftungsform") like this:

```
ggplot(daten,aes(x=Jahreszeit, y=Fracht))+ geom_boxplot() +
     facet_wrap(~ Bewirtschaftungsform)+ 
geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = 0.1))+
     stat_summary(fun.data=f, geom="text", vjust=+1.5, col="black")
```

My question is, whether there is a way to extract the exact value of the mean of eacht category of the factor?

Comment: Can you give an example of how the data set is structured? What does the question have to do with the boxplot? Do you want to include the mean in the boxplot or do you want to calculate the value of the mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach such a task using `aggregate` or `plyr`. With aggregate you get the group means (of Fracht I assume) with the following call:

```
groupMeans <- aggregate(Fracht ~ Bewirtschaftungsform, daten, mean)
```

Rounding is suggested for printing:

```
groupMeans$Fracht <- round(groupMeans$Fracht, 2)
```

Within the ggplot object you can then just add:

```
+ geom_text(data=groupMeans,aes(label=price,y=0,x=0))
```

The last term may require some tweaking for the x and y values to optimize the position.